# displaying a series of youtube embeds that can be hidden/displayed

Tags: php, javascript, loops, youtube, embed

My goal is to show a series of embedded youtube videos on one page but allowing the user to hide or show any youtube video by clicking a button associated with a specific youtube video on the page. I made a form that submits the youtube embed code to a mysql database and I created a php file to retrieve every embed code using a for loop. For each iteration of the for loop, a youtube video will pop up with a corresponding button which will allow the user to hide or show the youtube video.

It works when there is only one entry in the mysql table but does not work when more youtube embed codes are uploaded. For example, when there are two youtube embed codes uploaded, two buttons are created, but when I click either of the two buttons, it will only show or hide the first youtube embed. None of the buttons will show the second youtube video.

here is the code with some edits:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>hide/show iframe</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>

<style type="text/css">
<!-- 
#frDocViewer {
width:70%;
height:50%;
display:none;
}
-->
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function HideFrame() {
  var fr = document.getElementById ("frDocViewer");
  if(fr.style.display=="block") {
    fr.style.display="none";
  } else {
    fr.style.display="block";
  }
}
//-->
</script>

</head>
<body>

<?php
mysql_connect ("","","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("") or die(mysql_error());

$lastid = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM embed ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$lastid = mysql_fetch_assoc($lastid);
$lastid = $lastid['id'];

for ($count=1; $count<= $lastid ; $count++) {
  $iframe = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM embed WHERE id=$count ");
  $iframe = mysql_fetch_assoc($iframe);
  $iframe = $iframe['url']; 

  echo "
       <image src='utube.gif' onclick='HideFrame()' />
       <div id='frDocViewer'>
         $iframe
       </div>
       ";
}    
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because each div has the same ID. You need to create unique ID's for each DIV to show or hide ie. frDocViewer1, frDocViewer2 etc

Use your $count variable to echo it's value onto the ID as it will increment by 1 for each iteration of the loop.

```
echo "
       <image src='utube.gif' onclick='HideFrame()' />
       <div id='frDocViewer_{$count}'>
         $iframe
       </div>
       ";
```

Then you just need to make sure that you have corresponding Javascript for each of those DIV's. I would send the id into the javascript function using your onclick tag.

```
for ($count=1; $count<= $lastid ; $count++) {
  $iframe = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM embed WHERE id=$count ");
  $iframe = mysql_fetch_assoc($iframe);
  $iframe = $iframe['url']; 

  echo "
       <image src='utube.gif' onclick='HideFrame({$count})' />
       <div id='frDocViewer_{$count}' class='frDocViewer'>
         $iframe
       </div>
       ";
}
```

And then have the javascript code as something like:

```
var old_element = null;

function HideFrame(id) {
  var fr = document.getElementById("frDocViewer_" + id);

  if(fr != old_element)
  {
     fr.style.display = "block"
     if(old_element != null) old_element.style.display = "hide";
     old_element = fr;
  }
}
```

Then finally you need to change your CSS to make frDocViewer a class rather than a unique style. Notice above in the PHP echo string I added in the new class attribute to the DIV

```
<style type="text/css">
    .frDocViewer {
    width:70%;
    height:50%;
    display:none;
    }

</style>
```

PS: This code might not actually compile, it's just a rough guide.

Comment: do I need to change this part? #frDocViewer {
     width:70%;
     height:50%;
  display:none;
     }

Comment: oh yes you need to make that a class .frDocViewer and then add a class="frDocViewer" attribute to each DIV. I just amended my answer above.

Comment: Can I add a variable to the id like <id= $count.frDocViewer> and then it would access #$count.frDocViewer? or is "<div id='frDocViewer' class='frDocViewer'>" right the way it is? Would that change this part of the code too? " var fr = document.getElementById ("frDocViewer_" + id);"  var old_element doesn't have a value so should I set it up like this. Dunno if its valid or not: var old_element = document.getElementById ("frDocViewer_" + (id-1));
sorry for so many questions. I've only been doing for two months, haha

Comment: <div id='frDocViewer_{$count}'> will be fine as {$count} will be replaced with whatever number the $count variable is at so your ID will be id='frDocViewer_0', id='frDocViewer_1', id='frDocViewer_2', etc. old_element can be setup like this var old_element = null. Then it will automtically be changed by the code everytime you change the youtube video shown thanks to the line old_element = fr. You don't need to do anything else with this variable as it is just a temporary identifier for the youtube video that needs to be hidden when a new one is shown. Make sense?

Comment: Should there be an else statement after if(fr != old_element)
  {
     fr.style.display = "block"
     old_element.style.display = "hide";
     old_element = fr;
  }?                 Why does there have to be "echo" in 'HideFrame(echo $count)' ?

Comment: Changed the code where the echo was, sorry my bad. I also changed the javascript code so that old_element is set to null. Then in the HideFrame function, the code will check that old_element is not null before trying to change it's style.

Comment: Hey, it finally worked! Thank you from the bottom of my heart! Not to mention I learned the importance of CSS classes and parameters! I wasn't expecting such a fast response to my first post :D

Comment: Great glad your first post was a success! Don't forget to accept this as an answer by pressing the tick button! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with this line:

```
<div id='frDocViewer'>
```

IDs are supposed to be *unique* across the entire page, but you're creating a new element with the same ID on each iteration of your loop. I haven't tested this, but my assumption is that when your JavaScript executes to hide/show that ID, it's only picking up the first ID by that name that it finds.

You'll need to change your code to give a unique ID to each iteration, and pass a reference to that element when you call your `HideFrame()` function. The function can then operate on that specific ID.

Answer (score 0):

hmm...where to start....

if you `getElementById` where your id is `frDocViewer` AND `frDocViewer` is used by every video there will be problems.

how about something like

```
<div onclick='HideFrame(this)' >
    <image src='utube.gif'/>
    ....
</div>

function HideFrame(el) {
    ...
}
```

Not at all tested, but you NEED to go for something more GENERIC then hard coding an id....in my opinion